# A phrase as catchy as 'Feature Creep' but for underestimated projects

Tags: project-management, computer-science

I'm needing a term or established term to represent a phenomenon our company currently calls a 'Black Hole': a project that takes magnitudes longer than estimated, yet we're already sucked in and HAVE to see it through to completion.

EDIT:
Hoping that the best term will be voted up.

Comment: We call it "coming to work" at our office!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is [Death March](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_march_(software_development)), though I suppose it doesn't really apply if the project is ultimately successful.

Comment: Definitely Death March - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_march_(software_development)

Comment: Sounds like this is a contract type of project, which you're legally bound to finish, thus it can't fail, but your company just losses a bunch of money on it.  I've often heard these referred to as "Money Pit" projects.

Comment: It still applies to succesful projects. The term is about the jouney, not the destination.

Comment: It depends on likelihood of failure and what your company's definition of failure is.  Many companies don't consider going way over budget to be a failure, as long as the project satisfies the customer and the company doesn't go bankrupt.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "Underscoped".

I am involved with an underscoped project at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

"Scope creep" is the phrase I've used.

Comment: I'd expect "scope creep" to apply to projects whose scope is expanded, rather than just woefully under-estimated.

Answer (score 1):

I once interviewed for a position on what had to be the ultimate Death March project. I was at Lockheed Martin at the time. Here's what I discovered *at the interview*:

- The project was almost entirely staffed by engineers pulled off of the layoff list. Pretty much the dregs of the company.
- They were using castoff equipment from the rest of the company for their software development.
- 15 hours a week of overtime was mandatory, and would be for the foreseeable future.
- They didn't even have cubicles. Everyone worked in one great big open bullpen with wires strung everywhere.
- They had attempted to deliver this project once before, but the customer rejected it and made them try again.
- They were so far over budget and so late that nobody was even bothering to track it anymore.
- They wanted to cancel the project, but their customer was the government of Egypt and they were threatening to stop a large order of F-15s until this project was delivered. (The project had nothing whatsoever to do with F-15s). So now they were getting pressure to finish from the Chairman of Lockheed Martin on down.
- Engineers visiting the customer site in Egypt had come down with nasty staph infections. One had to be medevacted out to Europe.

I swear I practically *ran* from the room.

Answer (score 0):

Since hours are often associated with cost, perhaps the term you seek is [Cost Overrun](http://www.viswiki.com/en/Cost_overrun)?

I also like the concept of [Optimism Bias](http://www.viswiki.com/en/Optimism_bias) as the reason for under estimating.

Answer (score 0):

I remember 'logic bombs' applied to compressed files. Mainly, create a (back then, several gigs) file containing only one symbol repeated over and over. Zip the file (will become tiny). Send to user -> balloon effect.

Perhaps balloon project? 
Murphy's Project?

Answer (score 0):

[Spike](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/overheard/agile-development-glossary/) may be useful in trying to get these under control but it isn't quite what you want.